# Disable grails 2.0 resources processing, after deploy

Tags: grails, coffeescript-resources

I've packaged my app into a war (by `grails war`), and as I see, it have built all required resources. For example I have `coffeescript` code, that have translated to into `js` dir. Same for `scss`, etc. I mean I have all static resources, that can be served directly (and I want to server it from Nginx, not Tomcat)

But after deploying this `war` into Tomcat, I'm getting errors like:

```
ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [resources:1.1.6]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Ljava/io/Reader;Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode;
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Ljava/io/Reader;Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode;
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Ljava/io/Reader;Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode;
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.parse(JavaScriptCompressor.java:312)
```

This one is from `yui-minify-resources` plugin. Similar thing happening for `coffeescript-resources` plugin. Maybe it's because there is something wrong with this plugins, but it's crazy, because I already have all resources, prepared/processed/compiled to static files. I don't need this plugins on production mode.

How I can disable all this resource plugins on production mode? Is it possible?

PS same thing for `grails run-war`

Comment: any luck ? Whats is the resolution ? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @UmairSaleem don't remember how exactly, but was fixed by 'hacking around classloader' and upgrading all things to newer versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to `coffeescript-resources` and `yui-minify-resources` both having a dependency to Rhino javascript engine, but the YUI team has made [some modifications](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2008/10/80/) to their version of Rhino, which causes it to be incompatible with vanilla Rhino. You have two options:

1. Try hacking around with classloaders
2. Don't use YUI compressor

Comment: Related to option 2: we're shortly releasing a minifying plugin that uses google's closure compiler to get around this limitation: https://github.com/conmio/google-closure-compiler-resources